# how to show a block in all pages under right column except category page

Tags: blocks

I want to show a block in all pages under right column except category page.
So to identify category page `Mage::registry('current_category')`.
Where to specify this condition and how to show right column except category page.

Comment: i have used this in phtml page and its working <?php $category = Mage::registry('current_category');
if(!$category)
 echo "Hello World from catalog folder";
?> and local.xml  <default><reference name="right">
            <block name="catalog.test" type="core/template" template="catalog/test.phtml"></block>
        </reference></default>

Answer (score 1):

you have a option to reference the block only to pages and not include the catalog_category_default handler or unset the block in this handler  for this block if you are doing it via layout files

alternatively if you are doing it via scripting somehow then in the code you can check if you are dealing with category controller and exclude your content based on that

```
<?php Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getControllerName(); ?>
```